# Textbox should allow only Integer. not decimal in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, validation

I want to allow only whole values and not decimal to the textbox in vb.net.  Can anyone help me how to check validation on that.

Comment: Looks like asp.net, I've tagged as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only allow numeric input:

```
    Private Sub TextBoxKeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
            e.Handled = True
            If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = False
        End Sub
```

For a more elaborate example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644(v=vs.80).aspx